# Java server socket sending multiple messages issue

Tags: java, sockets

We have a java socket program where the server gets data from many devices and works fine. At times the server needs to send some command to the devices. When it sends individual commands it works fine. The problem comes when it sends multiple commands, only the first one is successful. We cant figure out why the rest fails. Below is the snippet showing how the message  is sent. Should I set a delay after a message is sent?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   

      new sServer7888();

   }
sServer7888() {


    try{
    final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(7888);               
    while (true){
    try{
       Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
          new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                       
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
       }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)     {
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}


class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

  private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }

    public void run() {

      while ((nextChar=readIn1.read()) != -1) {

         completeMessage += (char) nextChar;     
         if (nextChar == '*')
    {
         String[] splitResult = completeMessage .split(",");    
         String header=splitResult[0].trim().substring(0,4);

         if((header.equals("$ACK")){

          //update the message sent from the server as already acknowledge.
         }     
         else{
          //run query to find if there are any message to be sent out to the devices
          while(rsOC1.next()){
            commandText = rsOC1.getString("commandText");
            writeOut1.write(commandText);
            writeOut1.write("\r\n");
            writeOut1.flush(); 
          }

          //now process the normal message receive from the devices.
         } 
        completeMessage="";
       }   
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `rs0c1.next()` is returning true after first iteration ?

Comment: @VishalK yes I have checked that is it working fine because I got a lot of those message sent out.

Comment: It would be nice if you put here the code of client side receiving the message...

Comment: did you tried to look into behavior of writeOut1.flush()?

Comment: @Prateek : I think it is the good practice to flush out the OutputStream after every session of write..

Comment: @VishalK the client is a device so I dont have its codes. How to look into the behaviour of the flush();

Comment: @new14 What I am suspecting is, writeOut1 is connected to only one stream i.e., only one device. So, multiple devices wont even get the commands.

Comment: @Prateek no this stream is just for that one device not to the other devices. It can send the first message successfully only the other message is having trouble.

Comment: @new14: `writeOut1` is referencing which class?

Comment: @VishalK writeOut1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream())); and receivedSocketConn1 is private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }

Comment: What i think is that after receiving command from server the client (device) takes a long time in processing the command and by that time lot of packets already sent to the device So this leading to Late processing or no processing of new data sent by server. I suggest that : if you have any mechanism to know at server side if the device has already processed the last packet sent by it then use it in while loop as flag . If prev. command processed then flag becomes true and server sends new data.

Comment: @VishalK yes I am thinking of that line too. Do you think I should set a Thread.sleep(10000); after each message sent out to the devie to give it some room to process the previous message? After each message is process the device will send ACK on that message to say it has processed.

Comment: Don't sleep, don't wait for ACKs. This is all nonsense. You have a bug in your code and you haven't posted enough of it to show what it may be. Post more of the code so we can see how you write to the different clients,

Comment: @EJP most codes have been updated. When each message arrive we check is it an ACK message then we update the previous message status as acknowledged.Else we go in and run a query to check any more to be sent out and thereafter we do a normal process.

Comment: Writer with default encoding. That is like asking for trouble...

Comment: @JDB so what changes should be done then?

Comment: Use UTF8 or or some other explicit encoding, the same on both sides. Both readers and writers.

Comment: @JDB ok will do that but the core problem is still not solved right?

Comment: There is a good chance that this is your problem or part of it.

Comment: You still haven't posted the part of the code I asked for. @jdb I don't see any actual reason to believe this is a charset problem, any more than a sleep or ACK problem, or any of the other wild guesses that have been posted here. There's just not enough information to tell yet.

Comment: @EJP I have posted further codes starting from the main function setting the server socket and till the each of thread get started. Hope this helps how the client is connected and writing to the client is the codes which I posted earlier. How I write to different client is based on each connection made by the client then I write to them accordingly using the connection made by them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your device is sending ACK on Every message and Server is able to receive it then you can proceed in following way with your server side program.
**EDIT**
I have updated the code as per the requirement analysis. Let me know if any discrepancy is found after implementing it.

> `Thread.sleep(1000)` is not the reliable solution for above case because
>   we are not knowing how long the device might take to execute previous
>   command sent by Server .

```
    public void run() 
    {

        int i = -1;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((nextChar=readIn1.read()) != -1) 
        {
            boolean isCompleteMessage = readMessage(nextChar);
            if (isCompleteMessage)
            {
                String[] splitResult = completeMessage .split(",");    
                String header=splitResult[0].trim().substring(0,4);
                if((header.equals("$ACK"))
                {
                    String id = null;
                    if (i != -1)
                    {
                        id = list.get(i);
                        id = id.substring(0,id.indexOf("^"));
                    }
                    //update the message sent from the server as already acknowledge using id extracted above.
                    if ( i == 0)
                    {
                        list.remove(i);
                        if (list.size() == 0)
                        {
                            i = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            commandText = list.get(i);
                            writeOut1.write(commandText.substring((commandText.indexOf("^")) + 1));
                            writeOut1.write("\r\n");
                            writeOut1.flush(); 
                        }
                    }
                }     
                else
                {
                    //process here the normal message receive from the devices.
                    if (i == -1)
                    {
                        list = getRecords();
                        if (list.size() > 0)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                            commandText = list.get(i);
                            writeOut1.write(commandText.substring((commandText.indexOf("^")) + 1));
                            writeOut1.write("\r\n");
                            writeOut1.flush(); 
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        commandText = list.get(i);
                        writeOut1.write(commandText.substring((commandText.indexOf("^")) + 1));
                        writeOut1.write("\r\n");
                        writeOut1.flush(); 
                    }
                } 
                completeMessage = "";
            }   
        }
   }
   public boolean readMessage(int nextChar)
   {
        completeMessage += (char)nextChar;
        if (((char)nextChar) == '*')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
   //Retreive all commands from database and returns the ArrayList containing those commands.
   public ArrayList<String> getRecords()
   {
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       Statement stat = null;
       ResultSet rsOC1 = null;
       try
       {
            stat = con.createStatement();
            rsOC1 = stat.executeQuery("Query for message retrieval from database");
            while (rsOC1.next())
            {
                String sElement = rs0C1.getString("commandID") + "^" + rs0C1.getString("commandText");
                list.add(sElement);
            }
       }
       catch (Exception ex){}
       finally
       {
           if (rs0C1 != null)
           {
               try
               {
                    rs0C1.close();   
               } catch () {}
           }
           if (stat != null)
           {
               try
               {
                    stat.close();   
               } catch () {}
           }
           return list;
       }
   }
```

Comment: @new14: I think you should wait till `ACK` is received by server and then send the next command to client.

Comment: @VishalK we have an issue here because right at the very top we already have a line such while ((nextChar=readIn1.read()) != -1) which reads data from the clients. So how will this effect to the one you propose? We cant be blocking the readline because it might take some time to process and send the ACK?

Comment: @VishalK Why? TCP will deliver the data unless the connection goes down. And why should the server wait for an acknowledgment before proceeding? How does that solve anything? Not an answer.

Comment: @EJP: As told in Fundamental Networking by Esmond Pitt:For maximum performance in applications which recieve a lot of data at a time (eg.,the other end of an application which sends a lot of data), the receive buffer at the receiver needs to be large as possible within the constraints above, because TCP limits the sender according to buffer space available at the receiver—a sender may not send data unless it knows there is room at the receiver. If the receiving application is slow in reading data from the buffer, its receive buffer size needs to be even larger, so as not to stall the sender.

Comment: @EJP: Since we can't increase the receive buffer size at the receiver as it's a device and its code is not available So we are left with two options 1. Increase sender buffer Size 2. Sender send the data to receiver only after the receiver has processed the data(i.e. After Ack is received from Client). I did'nt consider first option because we still are not sure of how long the device will take to process each command so it might be possible that the sender and receiver buffer both are full and the Client(Device) still processing the Previous command.So I consdr 2nd option to be most suitable.

Comment: @new14: I need some clarification regarding your updated code you posted here. What is processed when "$ACK" is received ? What is the meaning of sending another command to client if "$ACK" of previous command is still not received from Client ?

Comment: @VishalK once the $ACK is receive we will update the status of the sent command to acknowledged in the database field accordingly. Thus we know this message was sent and acknowledged meaning it was received by the device succefully and processed.

Comment: @new14 : After a message is sent to client does Client send the ACK as reply in very next trip? or Client might send ACK after many trips?

Comment: @VishalK the client will send after every command send from the server as an acknowledgement.So it is still within the same socket connection. The ACK is immediate not after many trips.

Comment: @new14: Do'nt you think that if the connection with device stands for very long time then String `completeMessage` will be very large because you are not clearing it any time. All times you are concatenating a new character to it. How do you recognize the end of a message being received from client?

Comment: @Vishalk no towards the end after each complete message I will clear it in this form completeMessage=""; and this ensure each news message is indentified separately.

Comment: @new14: How do you recognize the end of a complete message being received from client ? Here in code it is nowhere seen.

Comment: @VishalK I have updated my codes to show how I decide to on the end of each message is ended with '*' and in the if statement towards the end after all the processing then I clear it completeMessage="";

Comment: @new14: ok That's is complete code . Now i would be able to think clearly about the problem. Let me see it thoroughly.

Comment: @new14: I have updated the code. Let me know if any discrepancy found while implementing it.

Comment: @VishalK thank you very much for the codes give me some time to grab it and understand it better before I could implement.

Comment: @VishalK I got one problem here in getRecords() I need to store the commandID from the db because once I receive the ACK I will need to update according to command id ? Where can I store the command id because return is just one type that is the ArrayList?

Comment: @new14 : It is very simple you can attach the `commandID` of respective `command` using the delimiter(eg. `^`) while adding records to the `ArrayList`. For example `commandid^command`. You can extract the `commandID` and `command` using `substring()` method of `String`. See the updated code.

Comment: @VishalK thx that was the idea I had so thinking maybe you have something else looks like that is the only way to go forward. Thank you.

Comment: @VishalK we are still testing and will give up some updates later.

Comment: @VishalK I wrote that book, and it does indeed say what you quoted, as far as I can remember, which has nothing to do with your answer and comments, which involve sending an unmotivated application ACK for each transmission received. TCP does its own ACKs, and its own window management. Layering more on top doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @EJP ..OMG You are that Writer!!!!! Esmond Pitt!!!! I was thinking of that right from the day I looked your other answers on networking related question here...I am so glad to meet you....

Comment: @EJP : And The line that i have written from your book is indeed over there.. But i was not knowing that You were talking about the ibuilt ACKs of TCP instead of the applications. But in our real time project , i also faced this situation. Server was sending data so fast and reciever was very slow.. And eventually after some times server stopped sending data...and the data at reciever end was all enqueued.. And if the Client terminates that moment , then all those data that server thought reached successfully to client were discarded and lot..So we used own ACKS..

Comment: @EJP Since you are best in this if not the for the ACK how will the acknowledgement take place then?

Comment: @new14: Just for curiosity I want to ask  How your code is working now.?

Comment: @Vishal it is working now but the problem is that the team is now having some other issues dealing with memory so they have left this aside for time being will update you with further details if anything comes up thank vishal for the idea great but I dont get why does EJP does not agree with the acknoledgement idea?